# list filter does not update the datagrid

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a list of agents and I am displaying them in a datagrid. After adding the search with filter option, any search does not update the items in datagrid as shown at [example](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/commands?filter=%7B%22status%22%3A%22ordered%22%7D&order=DESC&page=1&perPage=25&sort=date). I have a DRF based backend and using 'ra-data-drf' as dataprovider for the react-admin app.
Below is my code for the search component.

```js
const AgentFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="name" alwaysOn />
        <ReferenceInput label="Agent" source="id" reference="agents" allowEmpty>
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
)
```

Does the search function depend on the filtering capabilities of the backend? What am I missing? Attached is a screenshot where the search does not update the datagrid below.
[image: filter]

Comment: Not an answer but the example that you pointed out is using SearchInput: 
`<SearchInput placeholder="Search source="name" resettable alwaysOn />`

Comment: @MiguelAraya yes. I realized it after posting and reading through the documentation. I used the filtering in DRF backend and that resolved the issue for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the 'filtering' section of the [docs](https://github.com/synaptic-cl/ra-data-drf) say "is intended to work with django-filter's DjangoFilterBackend ". On enabling filtering on the viewset, react-admin started to filter the fields as expected.